# convert_to_threejs.py - Deprecated File Format

Tags: python, json, 3d, three.js

I am trying to render a .obj file to a page using threeJS. I have converted my file to .json using the convert_to_threejs.py script, no errors were reported during the conversion.

Now loading in the .json file using:

```
var loader = new THREE.SceneLoader();
loader.load('../models/testShape.json');
```

This then gives me the following console error:

```
"THREE.WebGLRenderer" "69"
"Deprecated file format."
 THREE.SceneLoader.prototype.load/xhr.onreadystatechange() - Line 38 of SceneLoader.js
```

This is happening with different .obj or .dae files, including examples from the threejs website.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try using ObjectLoader instead.

```
 function loaded(scene) {
    // do stuff
 }
 new THREE.ObjectLoader().load("../models/testShape.json", loadedScene)
```

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/4259